# Change background color mouseover and color link

Tags: css

I try to change background color div and link the same time, the link it´s inside div, the structures it's this:

When I put over the div my pointer, only change the background of the link but no more, the background of front_mn_item stay the same color

I don´t know it´s bad in the syntax, because I can´t change this 2 things, put over the div and change the color background and color link same time.

```css
.front_mn_item
{
position:relative;
width:97%;
height:30px;
line-height:30px;
margin-top:3px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-bottom:3px;
padding-left:1%;
background-color:#111;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:14px;
color:#fff;
}



.front_mn_item:hover a
{
text-decoration:none;
color:#111 !important;
background-color:#fff !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="front_mn_item"><a href="u">Home</a></div>
<div class="front_mn_item"><a href="u">Home</a></div>
<div class="front_mn_item"><a href="u">Home</a></div>
<div class="front_mn_item"><a href="u">Home</a></div>
<div class="front_mn_item"><a href="u">Home</a></div>
<div class="front_mn_item"><a href="u">Home</a></div>
<div class="front_mn_item"><a href="u">Home</a></div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.front_mn_item:hover` in that case?

Comment: I want change colo link when i put pointer mouse over the div and the same time background color div

Answer (score 2):

You need to include next **CSS** style also:

```
.front_mn_item:hover
{
    background-color:#fff !important;
}
```

Since, the next one will only affect the anchor tag style:

```
.front_mn_item:hover a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#111 !important;
    background-color:#fff !important;
}
```

You can check the next working example:

```css
.front_mn_item
{
    position:relative;
    width:97%;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    padding-left:1%;
    background-color:#111;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#fff;
}

.front_mn_item:hover
{
    background-color:#fff !important;
}

.front_mn_item:hover > a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#111 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="front_mn_item"><a href="u">Home</a></div>
<div class="front_mn_item"><a href="u">Home</a></div>
<div class="front_mn_item"><a href="u">Home</a></div>
<div class="front_mn_item"><a href="u">Home</a></div>
<div class="front_mn_item"><a href="u">Home</a></div>
<div class="front_mn_item"><a href="u">Home</a></div>
<div class="front_mn_item"><a href="u">Home</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the background of the div which is the parent of the `a` tag (the link) then background color will be applied to whole div and everything it includes, if child elements don't have its background color declared that is different from parent element.

Meaning you don't need to add `background-color` value to `a` if you want it to have same background color as `.front_mn_item`.

You should have written this:

```
.front_mn_item:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#111 !important;
    background-color:#fff !important;
}
```

If `a` has its own background color that needs to be changed when `.front_mn_item` is hovered then do this:

```
.front_mn_item:hover a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#111 !important;
    background-color:#fff !important;
}
```

EDIT: Update on first comment:

If you need to change `background-color` of `div` on `hover`, and `background-color` and `color` when div is hovered:

```
.front_mn_item:hover {
     background-color:#fff !important;
 }
 .front_mn_item:hover a {
     color:#111 !important;
     background-color:#fff !important;
 }
```

Comment: No woirks i need change link inside div , change color link when i put mouse over the div buy also change background div color